# How do I uninstall all user installed python and pip versions?

Tags: python, ubuntu

Also asked [at AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008492/how-do-i-uninstall-all-user-installed-python-and-pip-versions)

There are several python2 and python3 versions installed when I cheched `/usr/bin/` directory. I want to uninstall all user installed versions of python and leave only the version already coming with the operating system (to avoid any adverse effects). Then I want to install latest python2 and python3 through some version manager.

How do I uninstall all of the user installed versions and associated pip(s) ? to install newest versions of python using a version manager like `pyenv` or something.
My operating system is Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: you should ask this on https://askubuntu.com

Comment: @hop OK, I'll try my luck there! :)

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1008492/how-do-i-uninstall-all-user-installed-python-and-pip-versions